# Set createdBy field in document with current userId (auth.uid)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I know that Firebase has the `FieldValue` class, which can be used to generate e.g. a server-side timestamp when writing a document ([link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.serverTimestamp)).

What's the preferred practice for inserting the current user's uid into a document?

Having the client provide that field seems to allow misuse - unless I provide a server rule that checks for (new/updated) documents to match the `request.auth.uid`, something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /broadcasts/{broadcast}/chatMessagesCollection/{message} {
      allow write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find anything on the web for the use-case of having a document be populated with the user writing it -- so what's the best take on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing now with security rules to enforce that the provided UID matches the current user is exactly the right thing to do.  There is really nothing better (for this specific use case), and this is a common practice.

I've even written about it in this blog series: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-per-user-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-be67ee8edc4a